# When should I spend money in Forza 3 Motorsport?

Tags: forza-motorsport-3

I am getting by with just riding the gift cars, but it is really boring. I have 115k CR right now and at the start of season 2. When can I spend money such that I can buy a new car, and not have a good one for a while? In other words, when can I buy a car such that I can devote my entire time and earnings to it?

E.G. We can race class C cars now and I want an Acura NSX which is c class. But I dont want to buy it if next season I will be racing b-cars only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With each season, you'll generally move on to the next class of cars for the championship events.

I'd suggest spending credits upgrading cars you win, rather than buying new ones. If there's a axe you really want though, then buy it and even if you don't get suitable races in the season play you may find some in event list. World tour, endurance, etc. races typically allow any car in a class to play.